# Gradle plugins config causes "Unknown" in modules dialog on AndroidStudio 2021

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, gradle-plugin

I am facing a strange problem about gradle plugins config in android studio (**Bumblebee**).

When i added the following config in project level build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application" version "4.2.2" apply false
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Always appear "Unknown" in the **project structure** > **Modules** :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0KWy.png)

Replace with the following config everything is correct.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2"
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I don't know if I should use  `buildscript {}` or `plugins {}` .
Can anyone help me understand why this happens ?

gradle version: 6.9.2
gradle plugin version: 4.2.2